# Form validation in AngularJS-1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angularjs. I want to create a form and custom directive to validate each field. Is there any way by which I can create custom validation directives to each possible form fields. Separate validation directives to each form field - ( Text, Password, Text area, Checkbox, Radio button, Drop down, Submit button, Reset button ). Any help or reference is appreciated.

Comment: AngularJS already has several validators. You can define custom ones as described in the documentation of forms, in the section "Custom Validation" (unsurprisingly): https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation. Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, this is the standard way to do this-

```
.directive('validate', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
               ngModel.$validators.validate = function(modelValue) {  
                   //Your logic here, return true if success else false
               }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Because Angular has support for custom validators, and you're suggesting to use formatters and parsers instead of using validators.

Comment: I have updated the answer, I suggested formatters and parsers, because $validator is not available in earlier versions below 1.3, hope now its alright, cheers